# defining a fixed size array in a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, static-members

I have defined a struct in side a class. One of the members is an array with a given size.

```
class foo {
private:
  int N;
  struct entry {
    uint64_t pc;
    uint64_t offset;
    bool pattern [N];
  };
public:
  void bar()
  {
   entry en;
   en.pc = 1;
   en.offset = 2;
   en.pattern[en.pc] = 1;
  }
};
```

But the error is

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘N’
```

Comment: That's no a fixed-size array at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays. `N` must be known at compile-time. An alternative is using a `std::vector` instead.

```
class foo {
private:
  int N;
  struct entry {
    uint64_t pc;
    uint64_t offset;
    std::vector<int> pattern;
  };
public:
  void bar()
  {
   N = 100; //don't forget to initialize N
   entry en;
   en.pc = 1;
   en.offset = 2;
   en.pattern.resize(N);
   en.pattern[en.pc] = 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: that `pattern` is a bit vector. let say `00000`. Then I want to set one of them using `en.pc` to . So `01000`. Using vector, I have to push_back

Comment: @mahmood you don't have to push_back using a vector. Also, you can use a `std::bitset<N>` instead.

Comment: Still using `std::bitset` I have to define a `static const int N=5;`

Comment: @mahmood yes, that's true. Then std::vector. You can create a vector with `N` entries and then use `operator[]` just as if it was an array. No `push_back`, no re-allocation.

Answer (score 2):

N size have to be known at compile time. If you make in like `static const int N=5` it will compile.

Comment: I corrected this for use in class. I typically use fixed size arrays on stack to perform some on side operations. I have never used it as class member.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize an array, you must use a compile-time known integral constant. If you'd said `static const int N=10;`, say it would have worked.

Variable-length arrays, i.e. where the size is not known until runtime, are not allowed in C++.

One other way of doing this could be to use a template, e.g.:

```
template<int N>
struct my_struct {
    bool vals[N];
};
```

Or, similarly, use `std::array`, as in `std::array<bool,10> vals;`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a `std::vector` than a fixed length array in most cases. In this case you don't know the size at compile time which isn't allowed anyway. Given that it's a collection of `bool`, you might want to consider a `std::bitset` which is a lot more size efficient than an array of `bool`

```
template < int S >
class foo {
private:
  int N;
  struct entry {
    uint64_t pc;
    uint64_t offset;
    std::bitset<S> pattern;
  };
public:
  entry en;
  foo()
  {
    en.pc = 1;
    en.offset = 2;
    en.pattern[en.pc] = 1;
  }
};
```

Note that I've added the `foo` constructor, which may or may not now make sense given the switch to a bitset, and the object can now be used as follows:

```
foo<24> myBits;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the `N` is not known at the compile time. if you create a `ob1,ob2,ob3` then there is a possiblity that all the three object might have different value of `N` and which is against law of c++( variable-length arrays).

either use `const int N=5;` or  make a N as class variable `static int foo::N=6;`